# Convert.ToBoolean and Boolean.Parse don't accept 0 and 1

Tags: .net, boolean

Why was it decided that when parsing a boolean, 0/1 are not acceptable?

When parsing any integer type value, it accepts numerical strings to be parsed. (And if .NET can parse the string "One hundred million two hundred and sixty five thousand eight hundred and sixty five" I would be surprised).

What makes booleans special? They are essentially 0 as false, and non-zero as true in my experience...

Is there a bcl method to parse a string like this, and if not, why?

Note: I forgot to specify in a string "0" and "1". Curious though that if already an int it works as I anticipated. Maybe this caused the confusion.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

0 and (not-zero) are not equal to "false" and "true", they're just the representation chosen by C.  Other languages use 0 for true and -1 for false, or other schemes entirely.  A boolean is **not** a 0 or a 1, it's a true or a false.

Should it also handle "yes" and "no", "off" and "on", and all of the myriad other things that are analogous to booleans?  Where would you draw the line?

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, an explanation of why.

If some languages indeed use 0 for true, and -1 for false, I honestly think they are screwed up, but that is a great reason not to automatically assume through a parse that some developers may use blindly.

Comment: Why, yes.  Yes it should handle yes/no off/on.

Comment: To further explain why some languages use 0 for true and -1 for false, consider their binary representations:  `00000000` and `11111111`.

Comment: @MCattle: WTH? Does 11111111 sound falser to you than 00000000, or even -1? personally i think it's rightfully a matter of definition and talking about personal preference is a bit pointless, but looking at the binary representation did certainly not enhance my intuition on that one...

Comment: I thought that there was a convention: 0 = false, and anything else is true (usually 1, but also -1 if you prefer). So I would say 00000 is false, 1 is true and 1111111 is extremely true! ;). @Aric can you tell me in what language is 0=true?. The only example that comes to my mind is the shell, where you usually return(0) when the program finishes, but this is actually an error code (erro=0 -> error=false, so ok).

Comment: It's not hard to draw the line on this one. Things that have are generally accepted as true/false should be allowed. This would include 1/0, yes/no, maybe on/off. Taking such an inflexible stance on reasonable stuff is a good way to drive customers nuts, not write software.

Comment: Sql Server shows  / deserializes bit types as 0 and 1, so maybe if .net supported sql server at least... if Oracle stores them as 5 and 6 who cares.

Comment: So why then does "If "1" Then ..." Or "If 0 Then ..." work?!?

Comment: I use a lot of systems that have config properties defined in text files such as Arduino and APM etc. They all have a combination of string "true", "false", "yes", "no" so it is not always as simple as a data type of 0 or 1.

Comment: -1 It's really old post but it is completely wrong. There is no "0"/"1" conversion probably because creators of C# want to distinguish boolean values from integer values. But from mathematic (Bolean arithmetic) point of view inside equations using "0" and "1" is more appropriate then using "true" and "false". As such comparing to "yes"/"no" or "on"/"off" and machine code representation is completely false. [Boolean algebra on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Comment: @WEFX lol that's a bit brutal. let's start off with 0 and 1 at least before quantum computing takes over xD

Comment: Hey, leave 2011-me alone. He doesn't know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 36):

> What makes booleans special? They are essentially 0 as false, and non-zero as true in my experience...

That is an implementation detail, and isn't at all relevant.

`true` is a boolean value. `false` is a boolean value. Anything else is not.

If you want to parse something such that the string "0" evaluates `false` while anything else evaluates `true`, you can use:

```
!mystr.Equals("0");
```

Comment: Nice concise solution there, me likey likey!

Comment: And the string "true" and the string "false" are strings, not booleans. Yet nobody seems to have a problem recognizing their meaning when converting them to booleans. If we're smart enough to recognize that "true" means true then I think we're smart enough to recognize that "1" and 1 mean true, too. And we're smart enough to recognize that "on" and "yes" are affirmatives which can also be safely converted to true if the programmer is specifically requesting a conversion..

Answer (score 22):

The shared `FormatHelper`class shown below provides a simple solution using two variations of an overloaded method called `StringToBoolean`.

```
FormatHelper.StringToBoolean(String value)
FormatHelper.StringToBoolean(String value, Boolean NullOrEmptyDefault)
```

*Both variations provide a case-insentive string match*

**1) The normal convertion from string to boolean defaulting empty or null strings to `false`**

The following examples will result in a `boolean` value of `false`:-

```
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("0");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("false");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("False");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("no");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("off");
```

All other string values will result in a `Boolean` value of `true` such as:-

```
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("1");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("true");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("True");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("yes");
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("xyz blah");
```

*Note: Edit the value of `BooleanStringOff` in the class below to include more (or less) values for false/off*

**2) Follows the same rules as 1) above but allows a default value of `true` to be supplied as the 2nd argument to the conversion.**

The default value is used when the `String` value is empty or `null`. *This is useful if a missing string value needs to signify a `true` state.*

The following code example will return `true`

```
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("",true);
```

The following code example will return `false`

```
 Boolean myBool = FormatHelper.StringToBoolean("false",true);
```

**This is the code for the `FormatHelper` class**

```
public class FormatHelper
{
    public static Boolean StringToBoolean(String str)
    {
        return StringToBoolean(str, false);
    }

    public static Boolean StringToBoolean(String str, Boolean bDefault)
    {
        String[] BooleanStringOff = { "0", "off", "no" };

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return bDefault;
        else if(BooleanStringOff.Contains(str,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        Boolean result;
        if (!Boolean.TryParse(str, out result))
            result = true;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated this for C# 7 and above as an extension method with default values: https://gist.github.com/jamiehowarth0/5587d7d3731d58b10e0559c6e0efb4e1

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, this happens a lot in .NET. For example, I can't remember if it's XML Serializer or XmlConvert but one of them fails if the casing of True/False are not correct.

You can round trip through integer to get what you want.

```
string s = "2";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(i);
```

In the above case, anything non-zero will evaluate to true.

For this reason, I created a class I use all over called ConversionStrategy which takes into account the source type and destination type and chooses the most ideal (and flexible) conversion strategy for making the conversion.

Comment: The accepted answer sounds nice in theory, but when you see stuff like this there's really no rationalization that can make this make sense.

Comment: faster solution

Answer (score 7):

You want `Convert.ToBoolean(int value)` not sure what's up with the Parse methods :-)

Code for no useful purpose:

```
        int falseInt = 0;
        int trueInt = 1;

        bool falseBool;
        bool trueBool;

        if (bool.TryParse(falseInt.ToString(), out falseBool))
        {
            if (!falseBool)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TryParse: False");
            }
        }

        if (bool.TryParse(trueInt.ToString(), out trueBool))
        {
            if (!trueBool)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TryParse: True");
            }
        }

        falseBool = Convert.ToBoolean(falseInt);
        trueBool = Convert.ToBoolean(trueInt);

        if (!falseBool)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Convert: False");
        }

        if (trueBool)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Convert: True");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
  byte i = 1; //or 0
  bool myBool = BitConverter.ToBoolean(new byte[] { i }, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question would be hard.  Maybe because the narrow minded developers at Microsoft had their own reasons?  No disrespect intended to them.  Just saying they did not think about what it would need to be used for or how it would be used.  I can't think of a reason why my extension below would not work for anyone.  I mean a Boolean value is either on or off, true or false.  In my mind it's basically binary.  Parse methods for Int, Double, Char, Long, Byte, etc are more forgiving with their Parse methods.

However, consider this;  You are looking to see if a value exists in an object.  The same might be said for the following...

```
string myvar = "empty"; //Or maybe = "NULL"
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myvar))
{
    //Should this be true?
}
```

Anyway, let's just make this simple.  Here is my solution using an extension method to create a `ToBoolean()` method for a string.

```
using System.Linq;
public static bool ToBoolean(this string input)
{
    //Define the false keywords
    String[] bFalse = { "false", "0", "off", "no" };

    //Return false for any of the false keywords or an empty/null value
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || bFalse.Contains(input.ToLower()))
        return false;

    //Return true for anything not false
    return true;
}
```

Comment: To add to my post, I just happen to run across something on this subject today.  Even SQL handles Boolean with 1's and 0's.  `BOOL: Zero is considered as false, nonzero values are considered as true.`