# Pass integer value of radio button to sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to pass a value of a radio button to my database. when the radio button is not checked the value 2 pass in no problem. When the radiobutton is checked the value does not pass to the database. I get the error: "Input string was no in a correct format". below is the code:

```
Dim rbval As Integer
    rbval = Convert.ToInt16(RadioButton1.Checked)
    rbval = Int16.Parse(RadioButton1.Checked)
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        rbval = 1
    Else
        rbval = 2
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ethics", SqlDbType.Int))
    cmd.Parameters("@ethics").Value = rbval
```

I am sure its simple just nto seeing it!

Comment: Is the line rvbal = 1 getting executed or does a value of 1 cause an error?

Comment: [Why was it decided that when parsing a boolean, 0/1 are not acceptable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903776/convert-toboolean-and-boolean-parse-dont-accept-0-and-1/1903807#1903807) Choose your first or third option. I prefer the third because it's more legible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads as `Int16.Parse(RadioButton1.Checked)`. The problem with that is that RadioButton1.Checked returns a boolean value rather than an integer value, and thus the parse error occurs.

Based on your code, you can probably delete these lines and things will work:

```
 rbval = Convert.ToInt16(RadioButton1.Checked)
    rbval = Int16.Parse(RadioButton1.Checked)
```

So I imagine that your code would look like:

```
Dim rbval As Integer
If RadioButton1.Checked Then
    rbval = 1
Else
    rbval = 2
End If
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ethics", SqlDbType.Int))
cmd.Parameters("@ethics").Value = rbval
```

Comment: ok, I changed it to the following: cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ethics1", SqlDbType.VarChar)) cmd.Parameters("@ethics1").Value = RadioButton1.Checked                   It works fine when the radiobutton is not checked(0 is returned to DB), when it is checked i get the error.

Comment: That part you could have kept as-is. Only delete the 2 lines that I indicated, and everything should work fine

Comment: I tried that also but it didnt work. Then I thought to try varchar. Whenever the radio button is checked the value does not pass to database.

Comment: it appears that your table structure is not set in stone.  I would change the field type to `bit` and just bass the value of `.checked` as-is.

Comment: I tried this(bit) and "false" passes through but True does not, what am I missing? cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ethics1", SqlDbType.Bit))
        cmd.Parameters("@ethics1").Value = RadioButton1.Checked